# Forced global validation of String values in JSON body of Spring MVC controllers without annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I would like to ask if there exists a sane way to validate all string fields/values in a JSON @RequestBody of the MVC controller:

- all fields of String type are validated by default, unless overridden by special annotation
- the validation should check allowed characters and length

Solutions that I know of, but do not seem ideal for the use-case:

- javax.validation via annotations -- one must not forget to add the annotation, the validation should be performed on every string unless said otherwise
- org.springframework.validation.Validator most likely possible, but quite a lot of custom reflection code
- some kind of component scan in unit test that checks that classes with certain suffix in name (*DTO?) does have all String fields annotation with validation annotation
- use javax.validation + code-review

Answer (score 0):

We all know that we can use xsd to validate xml instance. If you want to go ahead with JSON as well. Maybe you need checkout [json schema](https://json-schema.org/).

As for java validator. You can refer to [here](https://github.com/java-json-tools/json-schema-validator)

Hope it can help.